# How to bring all customer attributes on CatalogRule?

Tags: magento-2.1, collection, customer-attribute, catalog-rules

I have requirement to show all customer attributes on Catalog price Rule Form.
You can see attached image for more clarity.
[image]

[image]

How i can get customer attribute collection and how i can display in catalogrule section you can see in screen-shot.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

We need to create customer model object instance and load the all attributes with that attribute.

Please check this following test code, this will help you .

namespace Custom\Test\Model\Config\Source;

```
use Magento\Customer\Model;

class Customers implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

    protected $customerFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }


    public function toOptionArray( $isMultiselect = false)
    {
        $customer_attributes = $this->customerFactory->getAttributes();

        $attributesArrays = array();

           foreach($customer_attributes as $cal=>$val){
               $attributesArrays[] = array(
                   'label' => $cal,
                   'value' => $val
               );
           }

        return $attributesArrays;
    }

}
```